# Android AlertDialog Builder better code

Tags: android, groovy

I got the below code to generate an Alert dialog in Android:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(actContainer).
            setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_attach_file_black_24dp).
            setTitle(strTitle).
            setMessage(Html.fromHtml(strHtml)).
            setCancelable(false).
            setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            Log.i("OptimGeek", "prrrrrrr . . .")
                        }
                    }
            ).
            show()
```

It's in groovy, actually it's working great, how can improve the "setPossitiveButton" to avoid the inner class ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SAM type coercion or [Implicit Closure Coercion](http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.2.html):

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(actContainer).
    setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_attach_file_black_24dp).
    setTitle(strTitle).
    setMessage(Html.fromHtml(strHtml)).
    setCancelable(false).
    setPositiveButton("OK", { DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i ->
        Log.i("OptimGeek", "prrrrrrr . . .")
    } as DialogInterface.OnClickListener).
    show()
```

Comment: Thanks 4 such elegant response ! . . . and thanks 4 the link, I'm missing new features on groovy

Comment: According the documentation, I could even avoid the "as DialogInterface.OnClickListener", it works fine, but I don't know yet the effect on performance, so I'll keep it. After all I just wanted to avoid the inner class declaration in java style. I can say that completing with "as DialogInterface.OnClickListener" just make mure clear code

Comment: Glad to help. If the answer was useful then you can accept it. Thanks